# puppet - how to ship same config file using two different classes?

Tags: puppet

I'm shipping a specific config file with puppet to all my computers. Let's call this class `class A`:

```
class A {
    # ship lightdm file
    file {
        "/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf":
        mode => 644,
        owner => root,
        group => root,
        ensure => file,
        require => Package["lightdm"],
        source => "puppet:///modules/my_module/lightdm.conf";

    } 

}
```

`class A` will actually be loaded through some other class:

```
node 'somecomputer' {
    include role::my_role #(will load class A)
}
```

Now, some user needs a special version of that particular config file. So I thought about writing a class `B` (which would look the same as `A` except for the `source` part) and include that class for the node config of that particular computer:

```
node 'specialcomputer' {
    include role::my_role #(will load class A)
    include B
}
```

However, I'm wondering how puppet will determine which file to ship in the end. Since there's no order of execution in puppet, it seems to me like my current approach won't work (plus the resource `file` will be defined twice which won't work either)

I also can not use inheritance on `class A` because `class A` is included by some top level class. So how should I deal with this case? any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide multiple sources, it will select the first that is available:

```
file {
    "/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf":
    mode => 644,
    owner => root,
    group => root,
    ensure => file,
    require => Package["lightdm"],
    source => [ "puppet:///modules/my_module/lightdm-${::fqdn}.conf", 
                "puppet:///modules/my_module/lightdm.conf" ],
}
```

Then you would have 2 files in the files directory:

```
files/lightdm.conf (for all hosts)
files/lightdm-specialcomputer.domain.com.conf (for the exception)
```

It's not exactly what you asked for, but I think that is what you want...

Comment: thanks! so puppet will know what config to choose automagically?

Comment: YW! Not exactly, it will replace ${::fqdn} with the fully-qualified domain name of the node. If it cannot find that file, it will fall back to the second one.

Comment: if I were to change the order of the source files in your example, would puppet use the `for all hosts` version? or would it still check the fqdn?